# How to model the sharp edge of a blade

Tags: modifiers, vertices

I want to make the edge of this blade thin so that it looks sharp, but how can I do this?
Should I use a cube instead of a plane or is there another way?
[image: Blade image]

Comment: You could loop subdivide the edge then extrude the new vertices to make a pointy ridge. Essentially, the edge of the blade should be edges (a single line of vertices) rather than faces (two parallel lines of vertices) like it is now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Mirror Modifier instead.

You can select the faces of your blade and then press <kbd>I</kbd> to *Inset* them. You can then move them some distance away from the Object Origin.

[image: Blade inset result]

You can see the effect of the Mirror Modifier:

[image: The Mirror Modifier's effect]

Answer (score 0):

This will make one side sharp, tapering all the way from the non-sharp side, like a real knife.

[image]

1. Apply the Solidify modifier
2. Merge the two edge rows on the sharp end of the blade

   - Edit mode
   - Edge select mode

     - **CTRL+TAB** > **Edge**
   - Select edges on sharp end of blade
   - **S** > **X** > **0**

     - Replace **X** with whatever axis is perpendicular to the flat side of blade
   - **A** (once or twice to select all)
   - **W** > **Remove Doubles**
   - Optionally, you can manually scale the edges on the other side to taper as desired (see picture)

This will only work if your knife is oriented straight along some axis. See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14774/how-to-merge-two-edge-loops) for more details on merging edge loops.