# How to combine two objects with smoothing

Tags: modeling, modifiers

What's the best way to combine arms to body without them looking like separate entities. Essentially, I want to melt the 2 together.

[image]

[image]

Comment: one way would be to cut the arm mesh before it crosses the body, make a hole in the body where the arm is supposed to join, then join the 2 objects with ctrl J and use the right click > LoopTools > Bridge tool?

Comment: @moonboots the edges of arm mesh where it crosses the body and the body itself doesn't line up so bridge tool won't work

Comment: Attach blend file (only arm+body) or screen of topology (but file would be better via  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com from )

Comment: @vklidu done. i have uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

What's not lined up? *Loop Tools > Bridge Tool* (as suggested by @moonboots) works for me.

- Join objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
- Delete last loop of Arm object
- Select end loops of body and arm
- Search for Bridge (<kbd>F3</kbd>) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Adjust vertices as needed to get desired shape

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There might not be a hole suitable to concatenate, or there is some topology flow conflict  when doing the edge bridge? Although those should be consider in first place when creating body..

Comment: I copy and pasted the meshes before modifiers to meet the size limit for the upload. My current mesh after subsurface modifier has alot more verticies. Not exactly like connecting 2 squares. But I've since remodeled as one object. Thanks for your input anyways!

Comment: Its always better start with lowpoly. Anyway It's hard to react (help) if giving file is not actual one. (BTW object like this -even with much more subdivisions, would fits upload limits I guess. Bridge works also for loops with different amount of vertices, see checkbox of this tool properties (3Dview left-down corner)  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30937/2214

Comment: @HikariTW I used model attached in OP ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use surface create(or converted) from nurbs. If you put objects near this create a smooth link surface between objects.