# One click merge two edge loops into one edge at center

Tags: modeling

When selecting a ring of edges Blender has a subdivide selected edges command to create an edge that is at the exact center (some call it the equator) of the ring of edges. Is there a way to merge two edge loops into one "equator"? If Blender can make an "equator" edge loop in a ring of edges with the subdivide command applied to the ring of edges, then is there a way to merge two edge loops into that same "equator" edge loop? I know there are work arounds for this. For example, make the "equator" loop in the desired edge ring and then dissolving the outer loops, but that is not a one click solution. Here is an image that I hope illustrates the challenge.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30937/2214

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a one click solution, but it requires different type of edge loop to be selected

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-click - select loop of edges.

<kbd>M</kbd> ⇾ Collapse

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Collapsing the rings makes them into an edge loop at the "equator".