# how can i fill edges between two objects

Tags: edges

I cut a hole in the landscape so that I can fit a cylinder in.
Now I want to fill the edges of the landscape's cut hole with the circumference of the cylinder - in a way that the cylinder will still be open.

I have selected the edges like that and then 'fill'

however the result isn't what i expected. It filled the hole on the cylinder... that's fine.. I can I delete those faces.. But it also filled the hole of the landscape in a way that cuts through my cylinder.

How do i achieve what i want?
Thank you for looking into my problem :)

[image: cylinder through landscape]
[[image: landscape filled cutting through cylinder2]

Comment: The tool's name is Bridge Edge Loops.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/is-there-a-way-to-fill-the-area-between-two-circles/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14774/how-to-merge-two-edge-loops

Comment: i've tried bridge edge loops, but had no results. just realised i have to join the two objects together first