# Connect 2 meshes together? (Missing vertices)

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm new to Blender and I want to connect 2 meshes together and make them into 1.
How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: If the 2 meshes are inside the same object, select the 2 edge loops and Ctrl E (or Edge panel) > Bridge Edge Loops.

Comment: @moonboots It looks as if there are different numbers of vertices on the two loops so the upper part may need to have the topology changed first.

Comment: Sure, but I guess this is another question, the object may look good despite the different number of vertices

Comment: Exactly same question here [How to merge two edge loops](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14774/how-to-merge-two-edge-loops)

Comment: Hello, FreakyHound, welcome to BSE. This _is_ a question that has been asked in several ways, before, so is a duplicate. Please try the answers you find in the dupes, and if still stuck, come back explaining why they don't work for you.